# How can i make java threads run in different cpus?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, cpu

Almost all threads are running under only one Linux process.
how can I modify my application to make it multi-cpu. 
When I use jstack command to view the process stack i can see that
most of work is done by this process

```
sudo -u orca jstack 15370
2016-05-17 13:50:45
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode):

"SET:4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b5a000 nid=0x3c70 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf206af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.processChannels(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"SET:3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b58800 nid=0x3c6f waiting on condition [0x00007fcf207b0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.processChannels(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"SET:2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b57000 nid=0x3c6e waiting on condition [0x00007fcf208b1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.processChannels(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"SET:1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b55800 nid=0x3c6d waiting on condition [0x00007fcf209b2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.processChannels(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.ConnSet$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"InconmingConnMgr" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a81800 nid=0x3c6c runnable [0x00007fcf20ab3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x00000006000383a0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x0000000600038390> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000060000fe68> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.VehicularConnectionManagerBase.processChannels(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.VehicularConnectionManagerBase.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.VehicularConnectionManagerBase$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"processRequestForActualGoSafe" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a7e800 nid=0x3c69 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf20bb4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"collectConnStatsGoSafe" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a7c000 nid=0x3c68 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf20cb5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase.collectStatistics(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"InconmingRequestMgr" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b0c800 nid=0x3c67 runnable [0x00007fcf20db6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x00000006000661f8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000006000661e8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000600066208> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.phprequest.PHPSocket.processRequests(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.phprequest.PHPSocket.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.phprequest.PHPSocket$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"InconmingConnMgr" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b08800 nid=0x3c66 runnable [0x00007fcf20eb7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x0000000600066340> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x0000000600066330> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000006000355e0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.VehicularConnectionManagerBase.processChannels(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.VehicularConnectionManagerBase.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.connection_manager.VehicularConnectionManagerBase$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"CypressFrameGenerator" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a91800 nid=0x3c65 in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf20fb8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000060007a790> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.cypress.CypressFrameGenerator)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.cypress.CypressFrameGenerator.backgroundProcess(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x000000060007a790> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.cypress.CypressFrameGenerator)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.cypress.CypressFrameGenerator.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.cypress.CypressFrameGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"VqXmlGenerator" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a94800 nid=0x3c64 in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf210b9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006000663e8> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.VQuebec.XmlGeneratorVQuebec)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.VQuebec.XmlGeneratorVQuebec.backgroundProcess(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006000663e8> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.VQuebec.XmlGeneratorVQuebec)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.VQuebec.XmlGeneratorVQuebec.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.VQuebec.XmlGeneratorVQuebec$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"MtqXmlGenerator" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b17000 nid=0x3c63 in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf211ba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000600066488> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.mtqxml.XmlGeneratorMTQ)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.mtqxml.XmlGeneratorMTQ.backgroundProcess(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000600066488> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.mtqxml.XmlGeneratorMTQ)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.mtqxml.XmlGeneratorMTQ.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.mtqxml.XmlGeneratorMTQ$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"TimeZoneCheck" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b14800 nid=0x3c62 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf212bb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.timezone.TimeZoneChangedManager.checkProc(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.timezone.TimeZoneChangedManager.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.timezone.TimeZoneChangedManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"processNewPingOptionActivation" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000b13000 nid=0x3c61 in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf213bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000600066c70> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager.realTimeBackground(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000600066c70> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pingOptionsNightlyProcess" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a9b000 nid=0x3c60 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf214bd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager.backgroundProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"processTripStats" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000aa0000 nid=0x3c5b in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf215be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006000670d8> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.stats.ReportStatistics)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.stats.ReportStatistics.processStatsThread(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006000670d8> (a com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.stats.ReportStatistics)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.stats.ReportStatistics.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.stats.ReportStatistics$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"processRequestForActualTC50" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a2c800 nid=0x3c5a waiting on condition [0x00007fcf216bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"collectConnStatsTC50" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a2b800 nid=0x3c59 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf217c0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase.collectStatistics(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerBase$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"DB connection reaper" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000009fb000 nid=0x3c54 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf218c1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.databasepool.DatabaseConnectionPool.run(Unknown Source)

"DB connection reaper" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000009c0800 nid=0x3c42 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf219c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.databasepool.DatabaseConnectionPool.run(Unknown Source)

"Log Sync" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000094c000 nid=0x3c3f waiting on condition [0x00007fcf21ad9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.app.logger.LoggerFile.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000007dc800 nid=0x3c3c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000007da800 nid=0x3c3b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000007d7800 nid=0x3c3a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000007cf000 nid=0x3c39 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000007b4800 nid=0x3c2b in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf2318d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000600021248> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x0000000600021248> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000007b2800 nid=0x3c2a in Object.wait() [0x00007fcf2328e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000600020c58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x0000000600020c58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"Main/ConsoleGoSafe" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000746000 nid=0x3c0a runnable [0x00007ffdefc84000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.console.EmbeddedConsole.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.console.ManagerConsole.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ManagerTC50.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at MDLoader.main(MDLoader.java:24)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00000000007ae800 nid=0x3c29 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000000075c000 nid=0x3c16 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000000075d800 nid=0x3c17 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x000000000075f800 nid=0x3c18 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000761800 nid=0x3c19 runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000763000 nid=0x3c1a runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000765000 nid=0x3c1b runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000767000 nid=0x3c1c runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000769000 nid=0x3c1d runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00000000007ef800 nid=0x3c3d waiting on condition

JNI global references: 157
```

Comment: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity

Comment: What make you think that "one process" means "mono CPU" ? One process can run on multiple CPU. Try to run the "top" and then press "1".

Comment: Threads do run on different CPUs by default though. You don't need to do anything. The thread affinity library can be used if you *need* to manually control it. It's very rare that you should need to.

Comment: actually my problem is that this process is consuming 235% of cpu.  modifying  my application to be a Multiprocess application  does solve the problem ?

Comment: Re, "my problem is that this process is consuming 235% of cpu."  Why is that a problem?

Comment: @ZouhaierMhamdiGeotentic how many cores? If 235% of cpu is being consumed (as reported by say the `%CPU` column of top) and you have 4 cores, around 1.5 cores are actually idle!

Comment: we have 8 cores, i think  the real problem is that i have many infinite while loop in the program which are listening for data to process (real time application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in your mind with respect to threads and processes. The way threads are implemented in Linux also might make it more confusing.

In Linux, each "process" has a PID. Each lightweight process also has a PID. What you recognize in **Java's thread dump** as a *thread* is a lightweight process on Linux. All the threads created by the main JVM process share the same address space.

But looking at the thread dump alone does not tell you which thread runs on which CPU (processor). In fact, the same thread can be (and perhaps will be) assigned to various CPU's based on scheduling algorithm(s) in Linux. At best, you can use other Linux tools to see how many processors (e.g. `lshw`, `ps`, `top`) there are and what they are doing.

This is further complicated by some hexadecimal and decimal identification. Consider this thread in your thread dump:

```
"pingOptionsNightlyProcess" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000a9b000 
nid=0x3c60 waiting on condition [0x00007fcf214bd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager.backgroundProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.orca.pf.tc50.rt_manager.ping_options.PingOptionsManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This thread has a native thread id of `0x3c60` which is same as `15456` in decimal. And if you invoke `jstack` on `15456` instead of `15370` (like you did), you'll get the exact same thread dump!

A great tool to correlate the threads in Java (as identified by the thread dump) and those at the operating system level is **top** and its [threads mode](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html). I have written extensively about this at [Top and Java Threads](http://blog.jymob.com/blog/2014/12/01/top-and-java-threads/). I could reproduce it here as well, but there is quite some description.

Your application already seems to be creating many threads. So, there is nothing (other than making sure you're not violating thread safety) you need to do in order for your program to take advantage of multiple CPU's on a computer that has multiple processors (cores).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of multiple CPU cores by using `java.util.concurrent` API.

1. Use [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) `newFixedThreadPool` API

   ```
   public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads,
                                  ThreadFactory threadFactory)
   ```

   *replace nThreads with Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*
2. Use `newWorkStealingPool()` API

   ```
   public static ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool()
   ```

   > Creates a work-stealing thread pool using all available processors as its target parallelism level.
3. Create [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and set pool size in below API

   ```
   public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                     int maximumPoolSize,
                     long keepAliveTime,
                     TimeUnit unit,
                     BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
   ```

   pass `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` as parameter to pool size.